# Significance of number of sockets in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sockets, processor

I was going through the license manual of the SQL Server 2014 and found the term "Socket" under "Max Compute Capacity".

For example: Standard edition's maximum compute capacity is to support "Lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores". I am able to relate cores with compute capacity, but what "sockets" have to do with compute capacity? And why should I care about the count of sockets supported?

Comment: A socket is the physical processor chip attached to the motherboard.  As of this writing, a single Intel Xeon processor can support 15 cores.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP - your comment is as good as answer bud. Got the idea, thanks for your comment/answer.